# How to create cookie of any website?

Tags: cookies

How to create cookie of any website ?

Example: When visitors visit my website, my website will create cookie of some website (example: http://google.com, bing.com). Like when you access directly to these links.

My English is not good but I hope you understand me !

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

You cannot set a cookie for another domain. Being able to do such a thing would be a severe security flaw.

If you want to set a cookie from a domain other than the one being visited, then you need to include a javascript file or a cookie-setting image from the target domain that will set the cookie for you.